# How to find out what a specific at job will do?

Tags: at

Is there a way to find out what an `at` job will do?
`atq` only gives the time and owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can do:

```
at -c JOB_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

`at` stores most of your current environment (there are a few exceptions including DISPLAY, TERM, SHELLOPTS, EUID, GROUPS, PPID, UID) and entered commands in a text file under `/var/spool/at`.

You can use:

```
$ at -C <JOB-NUMBER>
```

to view the contents of that file or you can do the following:

```
$ atq
Mon Jun  1 00:09:00 2020 a fpm
$
```

So your job is in the `a` queue and is number `1'

```
# cd /var/spool/at
# ls
a0000101949bb9
```

The naming convention ("%c%5lx%8lx") for this text file is as follows: first letter is the queue that the job is associated with, in this case the `a` queue. The next 5 digits are the job number, in this case `00001` i.e. `1`. The remaining 8 are semi-random based on the current time.

```
# cat a0000101949bb9
!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=1000 gid=1000
# mail fpm 0
umask 2
SHELL=/bin/bash; export SHELL
...
cd /home/fpm/tmp || {
     echo 'Execution directory inaccessible' >&2
     exit 1
}
${SHELL:-/bin/sh} << 'marcinDELIMITER63a7e9bb'
...
<YOUR-AT-JOB>
marcinDELIMITER63a7e9bb
#
```